# Dutch sea captain who circumnavigates the globe for a second time after being transformed

Tags: story-identification

The Dutch captain, who I think was meant to be famous but who had a grumpy demeanour, is transformed into some kind of creature that moves very slowly so the voyage will take him 1000's of years.  I'm not sure why he must undertake this second voyage but he is happy about it due to the fact that he has now been transformed, into whatever it is that likes to move and to think slowly and that also has tremendous patience. That's about all I remember and how I remember it although it may have involved him being abducted into the future as-well, or it may even have been the afterlife, but I'm not sure. It's an old short story from at-least the pre 70's I think, I probably saw it in a magazine of short stories although I might be wrong. Cheers

Comment: This sounds like some variant of the legend of the [Flying Dutchman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Dutchman).

Comment: Why do you keep deleting this question?

Comment: Why won't this stay deleted, it's not working

Comment: Because I've been undeleting it. It's a post that's evidently considered useful/interesting for the site, judging by the number of upvotes on it. Again, why do you keep trying to delete it?